# Get Apple ID security questions over email

Tags: security, itunes-store

I have forgotten the answers to my security questions, but I don't want to/have time to call apple support and have them tell me my questions. Is there any way to maybe reset/get them over email?

Answer (score 4):

No - Apple won't email you security questions.

You can self-serve at https://iforgot.apple.com or interact with Apple support. Emailing those questions would be a large security breach given that email encryption is not commonplace or supported for Apple's consumer support division.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you telephone Apple consumer support. They are pretty good. Be nice and have lots of information about your prior purchases.